# How to force https on Swisscom cloud foundry with Staticfile Buildpack (FORCE_HTTPS)

Tags: ssl, http-headers, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I configured the `env` option `FORCE_HTTPS = true` as suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/):

My manifext.yml

```
env:
  APP_ENV: production
  FORCE_HTTPS: true
```

However, when I open the website with http I do not get redirected to https.

I use a custom nginx.conf file

The setting was applied

Comment: Do you have a custom `nginx.conf` file or are you using the default one? Did the environment variable actually get set (can be verified with `cf env <app-name>`)? Which version of the staticfile buildpack are you using?

Comment: You can verify that the option was applied if you access the container using `cf ssh <appname>` and inspect the generated `nginx.conf`. 

Find the config in `/app/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` in the container. If `FORCE_HTTPS` is successfully applied, you should see a line containing `if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {` according to the buildpack source code: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack/blob/206728f929a69ed12570ee755b72e4cd5457745d/conf/nginx.conf#L50

Comment: I have tested the scenario with the demo app on Swisscom's app cloud. (Just publish a new static hosting app without providing a zip file via the portal). The http redirect worked for me. You can also check the config via console: `cf env {app-name}`

Comment: cf env output: 
    User-Provided:
    APP_ENV: production
    FORCE_HTTPS: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following line to my custom '/nginx.conf' file.

```
    location / {
        <% if ENV["FORCE_HTTPS"] %>
            if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            }
        <% end %>
        ...
    }
```